# on hover scale elements gets pushed

Tags: css

I'm creating a menu for a client and I got at hover effect on like this on two anchor elements:

```
a {
  margin: 0 2.5%;
  transition: transform .5s;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;

  &:hover,
  &:active {
    font-weight: 600;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}
```

This works fine but when I then hover over the link the link on the side of it gets pushed a bit. I reckon this is because the scale scales up the margin to or the width, but yeah can't seem to figure out how to do it properly.

Edit

I changed out the
`-webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
transform: scale(1.2);` 
to 
`-webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);` And got it workin, thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this, and you're done...

```
a {
  margin: 0 2.5%;
  transition: transform .5s;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;

  &:hover,
  &:active {
    font-weight: 600;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpfull to edit your question and tell what you have changed to the posted code and why.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it is caused by `font-weight`. When you do `:hover`, link will immediately change to different `font-weight` and for this purpose there is not `transition` effect, unfortunetaly.